# How to Hide/Show DIVs in Twitter Bootstrap for responsive site

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I am first time working on responsive site in Bootstrap and I am not able to decode classes like `hidden-sm` or `visible-md` etc.

Does `hidden-sm` mean to hide that particular DIV?

Comment: Check out that link by niyasc. It shows a very helpful visual answer of what you are asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is yes. If the div is added to the .hidden-sm class it will hide that particular div in a screen size of 768px.

If an element is of the class .visible-* it means it's visible for that screen size or above.

Example:

.visible-xs shows only in screen sizes <768px

.visible-sm shows only in screen sizes < 992px

.visible-md shows only in screen sizes < 1200px

.visible-lg shows in screen sizes 1200px and above

On the flip side you can accomplish the same with .hidden class with the other sizes.

If an element is of the class .hidden-* it should be hidden for that specific screen size range

Example:

.hidden-xs hides the element in screen sizes of <768px

.hidden-sm hides the element in screen sizes of 768px

.hidden-md hides the element in screen sizes of 992px

.hidden-lg hides the element in screen sizes of 1200px

Comment: `If an element is of the class .visible-* it means it's only visible for that screen size or above`

It is not what is given in official documentation.
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes

Comment: The stuff I wrote comes from blasting off with bootstrap, a course on Codeschool I learned.

Answer (score 1):

`hidden-xx` means that make particular section hidden in a screen size of `xx`

You may find more information here in bootstrap documentation
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes